# DeepSpeechDemo App works with Gradle cli but crashes when built with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, mozilla-deepspeech

The [android-mic-streaming demo](https://github.com/mozilla/STT-examples/tree/r0.8/android_mic_streaming) works off-the-shelf using ./gradlew installDebug, but when the play button in Android Studio is used to compile and install the exact same project it crashes with the following after tapping record:

```
2020-08-19 00:44:24.862 12872-12872/org.deepspeechdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.deepspeechdemo, PID: 12872
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28296)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28296) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libdeepspeech-jni.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at org.mozilla.deepspeech.libdeepspeech.DeepSpeechModel.<clinit>(DeepSpeechModel.java:9)
        at org.deepspeechdemo.MainActivity.createModel(MainActivity.kt:90)
        at org.deepspeechdemo.MainActivity.onRecordClick(MainActivity.kt:120)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28296) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The issue seems to be related to libdeepspeech-jni.so not being included when Android Studio is used. I am completely new to Android development (I'm building a Mozilla-STT React Native module and only supporting iOS is useless) so this is especially confusing.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Hours of random trial and error later: Changing this option from "Default APK" to "APK from app bundle"  in Android Studio made the demo start working
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-21 at 12 26 56 AM]

However, doing the same on my example app for the React Native module (which has a dependency android project which finally depends on the actual libdeepspeech) didn't work. It started working when using x86_64, so there must be no libdeepspeech x86 binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hours of random trial and error later: Changing this option from "Default APK" to "APK from app bundle"  in Android Studio made the demo start working
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-21 at 12 26 56 AM]

However, doing the same on my example app for the React Native module (which has a dependency android project which finally depends on the actual libdeepspeech) didn't work. It started working when using x86_64, so there **must be no libdeepspeech x86 (32 bit) binary**.